# How to initialize vector size inside a constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

How to initialize a vector in C++ to some specific size inside constructor with c++11? Something like this (vector called my_vec):

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H

#include <vector>

struct color
{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
};

class map
{
    private:
        int gridSize;
        int verticalNum;
        int horizontalNum;
        std::vector< std::vector<color> > my_vec(100, vector<color>(100));
    public:
        map();
        ~map();
};

#endif // MAP_H
```

This doesn`t work so I tried this:

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H

#include <vector>

struct color
{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
};

class map
{
    private:
        int gridSize;
        int verticalNum;
        int horizontalNum;
        std::vector< std::vector<color> > *my_vec;
    public:
        map();
        ~map();
};

#endif // MAP_H
```

and in constructor I tried to initialize it like:

```
map::map()
{
    this->my_vec(100, std::vector<color>(100));
}
```

But I get an error that : "expression cannot be used as a function"

Comment: If you know the size already, why not using an array ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you just specified C++11, in-class initialzation may be exactly what you want:

```
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<color>> my_vec = std::vector<std::vector<color>>(100, std::vector<color>(100));
```

Comment: Note that one doesn't have to specify C++11 to get C++11 answers. Rather, one would specify a restriction for the case where C++11 is not allowed (e.g. only C++03)

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it in the constructor's initializer list:

```
map::map() : my_vec(100, std::vector<color>(100))
{

}
```

But you could also initialize it as an in class variable as:

```
class MyMap {
  // ...
  std::vector< std::vector<color> > my_vec = 
    std::vector<std::vector<color>>(100, std::vector<color>(100));
public:
  MyMap() {}
  ~MyMap() {}
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49615b95acbaa1fb)

Comment: You *may* but you don't *have* to.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes I do, corrected thanx for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a *constructor initializer list*

```
map::map()
    : my_vec(100, std::vector<color>(100))
{}
```

However, if the actual code have a compile-time hard-coded size, why not use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead? Like

```
std::array<std::array<color, 100>, 100> my_vec;
```

Comment: You don't *need* to. You can use curly braces instead of parentheses. Or `T t = T(args)` syntax.